# Prove that $f(z)=z-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $z \in \Bbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ and let $$f(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}-\left(\frac{\overline{1+z}}{z}\right)$$Prove that $$f(z)=z-1$$

---

*My attempt*

$$f(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}-\left(\frac{\overline{1+z}}{z}\right)$$
$$f(z)=\frac{z^2+1}{z}-\frac{1-z}{z}$$
$$f(z)=\frac{z^2+1-1+z}{z}$$
$$f(z)=\frac{z^2+z}{z}$$
$$f(z)=\frac{z(z+1)}{z}$$
$$f(z)=z+1$$
But
$$z+1\neq z-1$$
Am I wrong or what the problem is asking me to prove can't be proven?

Comment: Second line: $\overline{1+z} = 1+\overline{z}$.

Comment: I forgot to add that $z\neq0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If conjugation is applied only to the numerator, you can rewrite the function as
$$
f(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{z}-\frac{\bar{z}}{z}
$$
which equals $z-1$ only if $z=\bar{z}$.

It's false even if you apply conjugation to the whole second term, so that it would become
$$
f(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}-\frac{1}{\bar{z}}-1
$$
and this is not equal to $z-1$ unless $z=\bar{z}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}-\left(\frac{\overline{1+z}}{z}\right)\\f(a+bi)=a+bi+\frac{1}{a+bi}-\left(\frac{\overline{1+a+bi}}{a+bi}\right)\\f(a+bi)=a+bi+\frac{1}{a+bi}-\left(\frac{{1+a-bi}}{a+bi}\right)\\f(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}-\left(\frac{1+\overline{z}}{z}\right)$$